# Apply ABS on range of rows and columns using macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet where the cells in the columns B to Y and rows 11 to 35 has a formula to calculate the value. However, now it is necessary to add ABS to each of these formula. Is there any way use the Google Spreadsheet macro to take ABS for each of these cell values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Arrayformula custom function

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(abs(B11:Y35))
```

but you need to put this in new empty range to expand its array